# How do I force NPCs to equip armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I have read that you can equip NPC's in on the PS4 version of Fallout 4 by hovering over the item on their trade screen and pressing triangle. This does not appear to be an option for me, as it just doesn't show this option and I have tried MANY different items.

Is it something I need to unlock or just another bug on Bethesda's part?

Comment: Which companions have you tried this with? Not every companion has every slot available. Nick can't equip apparel, which led me to think that companions in general couldn't equip apparel for while.

Answer (score 4):

It should work for any NPC that you have control over (read: access their inventory). That's basically **settlers and companions** but not traders or general pickpocket targets.

Items in their inventory can be equipped by pressing the assigned button/key for "EQUIP" (triangle for controllers, T for keyboard, by default).

Comment: The default button onXbox is Y

Comment: It doesn't work for *any* NPC, which might be the asker's problem.